# как вызвать переменную в другом классе?

Tags: java, javafx

короче , есть переменная которую я инициализирую в if'е , и надо как-то эту инициализированую переменуую использовать в другом классе , я пытался сделать через Getter  но выводит null, хоть и условие ифа выполняется . Как вывести эту переменную инициализируемую в другом классе

Comment: Опишите конкретно и понятно вашу проблему и приложите ваш код для ее воспроизведения.

Comment: у вас есть какой то код (код), у вас есть представление как он работает (ваше представление(код)), вы пытаетесь это изложить (ваш текст(ваше представление(код))), читатели понимают его по своему (читатели(ваш текст(ваше представление(код)))), таким образом ваш код прошел минимум 3 преобразования между кодом и понятием читателя и из за такого количества преобразований никто даже при всем желании не поймет о чем вы тут пишете.  Это все равно что слушать сплетни о вашем коде.

Comment: крч я нашел ответ на свой вопрос всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы создаете переменную внутри if, дело в том, что такие переменные удаляются сразу после выхода из if. Объявите переменную вне if, создайте для нее публичный getter и по идее должно заработать.

Comment: Если обратится к переменной, объявленной внутри if, из другого класса, то будет ошибка компиляции, а не выведет null

Comment: Тоже верно, в любом случае надо видеть код, без него трудно делать предположения.